# Android - Switching languages without reloading the activity

Tags: android, kotlin, multilingual

I'm currently working on a kiosk device for a public space, running Android. In the app, it should be possible to change languages while using the device (base language is English, other options could be French and German).

So far I have only found some hacky solutions for getting the app to change the language and all solutions so far requires the entire activity to be restartet, which is not really ideal since we are building the app with a single-activity architecture. This means that the app will restart completely when the language is changed and the user will lose all progress through the app.

Can someone help me to figure out if this is possible?

Current solution:

```
        val locale = Locale("fr")
        val res = resources
        val dm = res.displayMetrics
        val conf = res.configuration
        conf.setLocale(locale)
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm)
        val refresh = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(refresh)
```

Which works, but restarts the activity, and the app will go back to the first fragment in the navigation.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use "default" languages feature inside you have to restart `Activity` (due to reload resources)

so consider [saving properly instance state using `Bundle` and overriden `onSaveInstanceState` method](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#onsaveinstancestate)

you can also disable enter/exit animations calling `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` just before `startActivity` call

restoring UI in proper way + removing animation should cause immediate language change for user

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer!

I have some follow-up questions:

You mention "default" language features - is there a non-default way to achieve the same result?

I tried to use the overridePendingTransition(0, 0), but it still plays an animation when I change the language. 

I will take a look at saving the instance using Bundle, and return if there are any issues.